# onChange triggers only after 2 text inputs

Tags: javascript, listview, reactjs, react-native, textinput

I have a weird behaviour from my "TextInput". I am trying to filter a ListView based on a TextInput entry:

```
export default class SearchTabScreen1 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchText:'',
      data:[]
    };
}

setSearchText(event) {
    var reset = realm.objects('User');
    if (this.state.data !== reset){
    this.setState({
      data:realm.objects('User')
    });

    const searchText = event.nativeEvent.text;
    this.setState({searchText:searchText});
    console.log(this.state.searchText);

    var searchString = this.state.searchText;
    if(searchString != ""){
      let searchResult = realm.objects('User').filtered('name BEGINSWITH[c] $0', searchString);
      var filteredData = searchResult;

      this.setState({
        data : filteredData
      });
      console.log("FILTERED", filteredData);
    }
  }
}

render() {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
          <TextInput
            ref="recherche"
            placeholder="Search"
            autoCorrect={true}
            returnKeyLabel="search"
            underlineColorAndroid="black"
            value = {this.state.searchText}
            onChange={this.setSearchText.bind(this)}
          />
          <ListViewDico
            navigator={this.props.navigator}
            dataFromParent={this.state.data}
          />
        </View>
```

The problem is when I type an 'L', for example, in the TextInput the log: `console.log(this.state.searchText);` shows nothing.

The log shows this 'L' only after I typed a second character (whatever it is) and so on.

I always get a response at a "t+1 entry".

I would appreciate some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it happens is that `setState` doesn't immediately mutate the state, but takes time and as `Javascript` is async your `console.log()` gets executed before the state is mutated and hence you don't get the updated value, only when it is executed the next time you see the old value. The solution is to call the `console.log()` in the `setState callback`.

```
 this.setState({searchText:searchText}, () => {
     console.log(this.state.searchText);
 });
```

Code:

```
setSearchText(event) {
    var reset = realm.objects('User');
    if (this.state.data !== reset){
    this.setState({
      data:realm.objects('User')
    });

    const searchText = event.nativeEvent.text;
    this.setState({searchText:searchText}, function() {
         console.log(this.state.searchText);
    });


    var searchString = searchText;
    if(searchString != ""){
      let searchResult = realm.objects('User').filtered('name BEGINSWITH[c] $0', searchString);
      var filteredData = searchResult;

      this.setState({
        data : filteredData
      }, function() {
          console.log("FILTERED", filteredData);
      });

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I forgot about the setState ! But it also affects my UI:

When I type 'L' my ListView doesn't update but after I typed 'Lx' (or something else as 2 chahracters) I got all items beginning by 'L' in the ListView.

Is it possible to fix this ?

Comment: yes definitely, that happens because the searchstring again should be used after updating the state, or else use the value from `event.native.text`

Comment: Ok ty !

I directly used `event.native.text` and it's working perfectly now.
I used it within the if statement through the searchText variable.

My filter works fine now :) 
Really appreciate your help !